# Box2D | Disable dynamic body collision while still triggering ContactListener on collide

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I have dynamic bodies that I want to trigger an event using ContactListener when they collide with the player. The problem is that I don't want the player (FYI, the player is dynamic too) or the dynamic bodies to actually effect each other with physics (eg push each other on collision). I want them to simply pass over each other. Is this possible? I tried using filters, but setting them to different filters doesn't trigger the contactListener when they collide. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used Box2D, but it looks like you probably need Sensors.

Comment: Could you delete [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009447/box2d-make-kinematic-effected-by-collision) since you asked this question?

Comment: @JonnyHenly It's not the same asker, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set "isSensor = true" in your FixtureDef

e.g.

```
FixtureDef fdef;
fdef.isSensor = true;
```